# Can you use Mailgun to send and receive mails from Gmail/Outlook/Apple mail etc?

Tags: mailgun

As the title states. Can you add domains to Mailgun, create SMTP records, add these settings to GMail/Outlook/Apple Mail and use as normal mail accounts?

If so what are the settings you need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailgun is only good for securing delivery of your e-mail.